# Python 2.6, what does the % mean in this context?

Tags: python, syntax, modulo

```
def f(x):
    return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
```

Just learning the language, I thought `%` was for string formatting?

Found on the official tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.1/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: f(x) would return 1 if the number is not divisible by 2 and not divisble by 3

Comment: @anijhaw : it could return 2 if not divisible by 3. In fact for x % y, where y and x are integers and y > x, the return values range from 0 to y-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of numbers it means modulo -- the remainder you get when you divide x by 2 is x % 2.

Answer (score 2):

That, my friend, would be the modulo operator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation for what that is and http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations for all binary arithmetic operators in python.

Answer (score 0):

It is the modulo operator, so that your function returns true if and only if the number x doesn't divide by 2 and doesn't divide by 3.  x % y represents the remainder of dividing x by y. For Example 5%2 = 1 and 5%3 = 2 and thus, for number 5, your method above returns true.